# Main Menu responsive issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, overflow

I was working on this [site](http://beta.jointviews.com/) for its mobile responsivenes.after a few css edits I managed to make it responsive.I tested in different browsers.its working fine but not in mozilla firefox.when we scroll down to the bottom of the page it shows a horizontal scrollbar.just in mozilla.then i figured out its the issue with menu so i changed the css to following

```
ul#menu-main{overflow:hidden;}
```

it solved the issue but the dropdown menu was not showing which was showing before i changed the above css.so I reveretd back.
is there any other css to make it responsive in mozilla without hiding the dropdown submenu? thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be the solution to the problem. In the `container` div, instead of using `overflow:auto`, use `overflow:hidden`.

I inspected and checked with firebug and it worked for me